# $.getJSON callback function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get data from json file to render tilemap. But I am getting this error all the time `Uncaught ReferenceError: renderTileMap is not defined`.

I tried to place body of renderTileMap function into $.getJSON function and it works. Map is rendered in 0.2 ms so no long waiting.
JSON file is also correct. I have no idea why javascript cannot see this method.

```
getData() {
    $.getJSON(this.file, renderTileMap);
}

renderTileMap(json) {
    var actPosX = this.beginPosX;
    var actPosY = this.beginPosY;
    var activeTile = 0;

    var tiles = json.tiles;
    var tilesResources = json.tilesResources;
    var lines = tiles.length / this.lineSize;
    var i, y;
    for(i = 1; i < lines; i++) {
        for(y = 1; y < this.lineSize; y++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = tilesResources[tiles[activeTile]];
            ctx.fillRect(actPosX,actPosY, this.tileWidth, this.tileHeight);
            actPosX += this.tileWidth;
            activeTile++;
        }
        actPosY += this.tileHeight;
        actPosX = this.beginPosX;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `this.renderTileMap`

Comment: And where is `renderTileMap(json)`  defined? There is not `function`  in front of it so it looks like a class method. If so then there is a `this.`  missing in front of `renderTileMap`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Dont know how I couldn´t see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `file` and `renderTileMap` aren't variables of the `getData` method, they are part of the context of `getData` (the object it is in). You can access the context via `this` so it has to be:

```
   $.getJSON(this.file, this.renderTileMap);
```

Now while the callback gets called now, it looses its context, so you have to bind it:

```
  $.getJSON(this.file, this.renderTileMap.bind(this));
```

Read on:

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

[MDN - this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @filip glad to help :)